# In Python, How can I get a list of ranges of everything between a start point and an end point?

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
numbers = [-2, -2, -2, -5, -5, 6, 6, -2, -2, 5, 5, -2, -2, 4, 4, -2, -2]

start_index = None

super_ranges=[]

for i, num in enumerate(numbers):
    # If we haven't started a new range yet
    if start_index is None:
        start_index = i
        current_station_value = num
    else:
        if num == current_station_value:
            new_start_index=i
        if num != numbers[new_start_index]:
            super_ranges.append(numbers[new_start_index])
            super_ranges.append(num)

print(super_ranges)
```

Desired output = [-2, -5, -5, 6, 6, -2], [-2, 5, 5, -2], [-2, 4, 4, -2]]

Answer (score 0):

Your code adds items but never adds sublists.  You can use your index tracking to get subscripts of the original list instead of adding individual items.

```
numbers = [-2, -2, -2, -5, -5, 6, 6, -2, -2, 5, 5, -2, -2, 4, 4, -2, -2]

start  = 0
ranges = []
for i,n in enumerate(numbers):
    if i > start and n == numbers[start]:
        ranges.append(numbers[start:i+1])
        start = i+1
        
print(ranges)
                      
[[-2, -2], [-2, -5, -5, 6, 6, -2], [-2, 5, 5, -2], [-2, 4, 4, -2]]
```